# Django - Use admindocs to Auto-Generate Documentation for Own Code

Tags: django, documentation

Is thre a way to use the `django.contrib.admindocs` package to generate HTML/PDF documentation for my own models and views and functions I have in seporate `.py` files

Comment: Too broad? :facepalm:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

possible -- depends on how the docs for your files are structured

If you're just looking to generate user friendly docs from your python files you may be better off with [Python Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/)

pretty much the standard for generating HTML documentation -- same system used on ReadTheDocs

Comment: Can you then connect compiled sphinx html docs with django admin so only staff users can see them?

Comment: couple ways, first I think of is copy the sphinx docs to a template folder and create a custom url/view that maps out that directory with restrictions for staff only -- then add a link to that section in the admin template -- probably more elegant ways to accomplish this but provides a starting point

Comment: Thanks Alvin! Actually I've made a reusable app for exactly this purpose: [django-docs](http://django-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) ;)

Comment: How to include the data schema (like what admindocs has) into Sphinx?